# How to setIsAccessibilityElement with Monotouch?

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

There's a method `setIsAccessibilityElement` on `UIView` in `Obj-C`.
What is the equivalent in `Monotouch`?

I don't see any similar method/property except `AccessibilityDecrement/AccessibilityIncrement`, but that's probably something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [UIResponder helper class](https://gist.github.com/3599186) to access isAccessibilityElement.